# How to find the fundamental solution of nonhomogeneous linear second order differential equation?

Tags: fundamental-solution

I have a  second-order nonhomogeneous linear differential equation, and its solution satisfies:
\begin{alignat}{10}
y(1)&{}={}& c_1x^2 & & &{}+{}& c*\cos x\\
y(2)&{}={}& c_2x^2 &{}-{}& c_3x &{}+{}& c*\cos x\\
y(3)&{}={}&    x^2 &{}-{}& c_4x &{}+{}& c*\cos x
\end{alignat}
What is the set of fundamental solution for this kind of differential equation?

I think the fundamental set of solutions is: $\{x^2-x,\cos x\}$.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, since you mention differential equation, but no derivatives are mentioned in the text of the problem.

Comment: What means "it's solution satisfies" ?